# MapReduce with Hadoop: Type mismatch in key from map

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a simple wordcount program, and I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

What is the meaning of this, and how do I rectify it??

Comment: It means something you've done expected a `Text`, and it got a `LongWritable`. Somewhat difficult to know how to assist with rectification since we cannot see your code.

Comment: i agree, you should at least post some code

Comment: sorry guys, i forgot to post code. Anyway, its working now! I followed @shailesh's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of the following lines in your main function:

```
 conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

assuming you're using JobConf conf;

OR

```
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

assuming you're using Job job = new Job();

Comment: Thanks. It is maddening that this blows up at runtime when all the information to detect the mistake is already in the type system.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving an input of a sequence file which has `LongWritable` as the key where as the expected sequence file should have the key as `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you are using TextInputFormat as you input format class..It generates keys of type LongWritable and values of type Text..But maybe your application expects keys of type Text..That's why when you set MapOutputKeyClass explicitly as indicated by shailesh using "job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class)" it works for you.